# form validation and record insert not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Form validation and record insert not working in codeigniter

model

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model
{

  function insert($data)
  {
    $this->db->insert("users", $data);
  }
}
```

controller

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Mycontroller extends CI_controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('myfolder/my_page');

    }

    function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('myfolder/login');
    }

    function signup()
    {
        $this->load->view('myfolder/signup');
    }

    function signupmethod()
    {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name",'requird|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","Last Name",'requird|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email","Email",'requird|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","Password",'requird|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("mobile","Mobile",'requird|alpha');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
        {
            $this->load->model("mymodel");

            $data = array(
                "firstname" => $this->input->post("firstname"),
                "lastname" => $this->input->post("lastname"),
                "email" => $this->input->post("email"),
                "password" => $this->input->post("password"),
                "mobile" => $this->input->post("mobile"),
                "curtime" => "NOW()"
            );

            if($this->input->post("Signup"))
            {
                $this->mymodel->insert($data);
                redirect(base_url() . "mycontroller/Inserted");
            }
        }
    }

    public function Inserted()
    {
        $this->index();
    }

}

   ?>
```

view(html code)

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo   base_url()?>mycontroller/signupmethod" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <h3>Login</h3>
   </div>

     <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("firstname"); ?></span>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("lastname");  ?></span>
        </div>

       </div>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("email"); ?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("password"); ?></span>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" class="form-control">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("mobile"); ?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 form-group" style="margin-top: 23px;">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-info">
    </div>

</div>
```

I have read every line carefully, code run but no errors showing and validation and record insert are not working. and no errors showing.
please help.

Comment: var_dump($data) in model / controller if data is comming or not...

Comment: Have you check all error log ?

Comment: @Ash
sir not comming data

Comment: @Shahnawaz
sir in error log, not errors showing.
and also validation not working.

Comment: @shiv you did not handle error coming from form_validation.. if error occure in form_validation then there is no else to show error.... to test , set else{echo "error"} & check if error string coming or not

Comment: Check your validation statements... `requird` is not correct. `required` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change controller this block of code when you fetch form elements in controller always use the element name

```
if($this->input->post("submit"))
{
      $this->mymodel->insert($data);
      redirect(base_url() . "mycontroller/Inserted");
}
```

Comment: can you just try only trim|required so we find where we are wrong.

Comment: have you loaded form and url helper?

Answer (score 0):

Correct spelling of required

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name",'required|alpha');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your set_rules statements are incorrect. Use `required` instead of `requird` otherwise set_rules will fail.

When you are not sure why form_validation is failing, try getting the errors with:

```
If($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    echo validation_error();
}
```